# Resharper sort properties, fields by name on file saving

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper, codemaid

I use Resharper 8.2 with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.
Is it possible to setup this environment to sort method, fields, property by alphabet, but only when I save file?
I know that CodeMaid has this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found nuget package which allow to reformat code according to re# rules on file saving. Below is link to it

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b5445a42-8c98-43cc-a4c5-7f7496f647c6